# Google Picker API Disable submission confirmation modal window

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-picker

A few days ago, when downloading files to disk, a modal confirmation window for sending files began to appear.
How can I disable a given modal window.

[I use the code from the example](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#file-open_dialogs)

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7AU0.png)

Comment: I also am getting this. I would think its a change Google made for security purposes, though if you like, you can always request this as a feature. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191628&template=823914

Comment: I created a theme but there is no result. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/184420269

Comment: Same probem here...